# dir /b command output in one line with DELIMITER added Batch file programming

Tags: batch-file

I want dir /b command line output in one line separated by a delimiter
for example 
Outout of

```
dir c:\test 
file1
file2
file3
file4
```

I want it as

```
file1;file2;file3;file4
```

How to do this in batch programming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
set LIST=
for %%x in (*) do set LIST=!LIST!;%%x
echo %LIST:~1%
```

This won't quote file names that happen to contain a `;`, though. The following does, though:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
set LIST=
for %%x in (*) do (
  echo %%x|findstr ";">nul 2>&1
  if errorlevel 1 (set LIST=!LIST!;%%x) else (set LIST=!LIST!;"%%x")
)
echo %LIST:~1%
```

Comment: But where is dir command? I got result factor.log;session.log what is it?

Comment: `dir` is not necessary since the `for` loop iterates over the files instead.

Comment: But how to specify needed folder? and get same result in text file as `dir /a:d /b с:\folder\ | sort > %file%`

Comment: `for %%x in (c:\folder\*) do ...` but that won't sort, of course.

Comment: `for /f %%x in ('dir C:\folder /a:d /b') do [...]` If you want to know more about "for", just type `for /?`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe pipe it through a python script such as:

```
import sys
print ';'.join(sys.stdin.read().split())
```

In your batch file:

```
dir /b | thatscriptjustabovehere.py
```