# How to get the command line output to be in one line with delimiter comma ","

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have this command that give me the host name of the computer and the members of the local administrators group.

```
echo %computername% > \\folder\%computername%.txt

net localgroup Administrators | findstr /V Alias | findstr /V Members | findstr /V Comment | findstr /V The | findstr /v "^$" | more +1 >> \\folder\%computername%.txt
```

The result now is:

Computer1

Administrator

Domainname\Domain Admins

User

I want it to be in one line:
Computer1, Administrator, Domainname\Domain Admins, User

I cant seem to get there, Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

I tried with the | tr '\n' ','
'tr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

I also tried with this thred
[dir /b command output in one line with DELIMITER added Batch file programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813273/dir-b-command-output-in-one-line-with-delimiter-added-batch-file-programming)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenating lines together in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53384288/concatenating-lines-together-in-a-batch-file)

Comment: `tr` is a POSIX tool so obviously if you're not on \*nix or didn't install POSIX tools on Windows then it won't be available

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you expected.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /F "delims=" %%i in ('net localgroup Administrators ^| findstr /V "^-" ^| findstr /V Alias ^| findstr /V Members ^| findstr /V Comment ^| findstr /V The ^| findstr /v "^$"') do (
    if not defined output (
        set "output=%%i"
    ) else (
        set "output=, !output!, %%i"
    )
)

echo %computername%!output!> %computername%.txt
```

`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` enable delayed variable expansion, which allows the variables to be expanded within the FOR loop.

it provide the following contents in the file

```
ComputerName, Administrator, Username
```

Comment: hi thank you but if you can help with onw more thing:
the script that you made is givin me to commas after the computer1,
computer1, , administrator, Domain Admins, Enterprise Admins.
how can i delete one comma?

Comment: yeah sure why not. In my case there is same output which i shared with you, so in idk form where you are getting that **"extra"** comma. but we can give it a try. remove the comma next to the `=` sign from `set "output=, !output!, %%i"` and put it after `!output!` in the last statement i.e. `echo %computername%,!output!> %computername%.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do it more simply using PowerShell from your batch file:

```bash
powershell.exe -NoP "$Env:Computername + ',' + ($(GCim Win32_Group -F \"SID='S-1-5-32-544'\" -P Name | GCAI -Resu Win32_UserAccount).Name -Join ',')"
```

I'll leave you to decide upon the best way to output it to a file as needed.